# How should call method of child that is inside <slot> tag?

Tags: vue.js

Please help me out. I am working on Vue js project in typescript with dynamic components loading. I am using  to load component names from array and each have a parent wrapper component and inside that wrapper I used  to render child component. Now i want to access a method of child component that is loaded in the  from wrapper component.

I tried with $slot feature but no luck also I tried event bus but then method calls in multiple child components.

```
<Wrapper>
  <component :is="propsData.componentName" :key="key"></component>
</Wrapper>
```

in side Wrapper component

```
<div class="container">
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

I want to call method written in the dynamic loaded component from Wrapper component when some event occurs.

Comment: You must avoid call methods on this way, it is a bad practice. Try use events using Vuex, it's better and clean.

Comment: Yes @Luis, I am using Vuex store to pass data to dynamic components but now I want to call child methods from parent components and child components are loaded dynamically. in the slot of parent component.

Comment: Your child component react to VueX data change, you can use this approach to call whatever you want in child components. Make children watch VueX props and then do what they need. Does this apply?

Comment: @SuhasBhosale if you happen to find a solution to your problem or would like to share your own solution feel free to answer your own question and accept that as an answer. That way everyone can learn and the question won't remain unanswered.

Comment: @etarhan I am currently using ```this.$children[1][childmethod]()``` but I want event driven solution. that I wont find yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the Wrapper components children through the [**`$children`**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children) prop, this will return an array of components. An example usage would be as follows (calling a child components method named **`childMethod`** for example):

```
this.$children[0].childMethod()
```

Although the code above would work, it is generally not considered a good practice. It would be better to emit an event from the child component and listen to this event, after which you can run your logic in you Wrapper component.

Comment: Hi @etarhan that would work but that is tight coupling in between these two components and I want components should be loosely coupled. is there any other way to access the child method without tight coupling them.

Comment: You could pass a prop to Wrapper with the method name and use that to call the child method. this.children[0][childMethod]() for example, although you should really look into something like vuex to achieve the uncoupling you desire because anything i just mentioned i would not really recommend.